# How to create MutableProperty<T> from MutableProperty<U> in Swift ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa-4

Is there any easy way to create MutableProperty from MutableProperty in Swift ReactiveCocoa 4?

I have a case that, and I want an way to create classB with classA, in which I need to setup statusB with statusA, but how to do this?

```
class ClassA {
  var statusA = MutableProperty<T>
}

class ClassB {
    var statusB = MutableProperty<U>

    func getStatusB(from StatusA: T) -> U {
        // .. assume this is implemented.
    }

    init(statusB: U) {
        //...
    }

    convenience init(from classA: ClassA) {
        self.statusB = // here how to setup this value from classA's statusA with getStatusB(from:)?
    }
}
```

Comment: I found similar at https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2183

Comment: after map(..)  MutableProperty<T>  become AnyProperty<U>, but not MutableProperty<U>

Answer (score 0):

you can't make a `MutableProperty<U>` directly from a `MutableProperty<T>`  but you can make a `MutableProperty<U>` with initial value `getStatusB(from: classA.statusA.value)` and then bind it to `classA.statusA.signal.map(getStatusB)` so all changes to the `MutableProperty<T>` propagate to the `MutableProperty<U>`, like

```
convenience init(from classA: ClassA) {
    self.init(getStatusB(from: classA.statusA.value)))
    self.statusB <~ classA.statusA.signal.map(getStatusB)
}
```

(however for this to compile, `getStatusB` can't be an instance method of `ClassB` because you need to be able to call it before you call `self.init`)